# Why No name servers found at child?

Tags: domain-name-system

No name servers found at child.

1. Superfluous name server listed at parent: ***ns3.soonce.com***
2. Superfluous name server listed at parent: ***ns4.soonce.com***

Why am I getting this error [here](http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=soonce.com)?

But not [here](http://www.intodns.com/soonce.com)?

Running a cPanel server on ns3 + cPanel DNS Only on ns4. What does it really mean and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NS3 does not respond to queries for itself and the other name server:

```
$ dig @83.169.20.193 ns4.soonce.com

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4-P3 <<>> @83.169.20.193 ns4.soonce.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 23542
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns4.soonce.com.            IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
soonce.com.     86400   IN  SOA ns3.soonce.com. info.soonce.com. 2012022101 86400 7200 3600000 86400

;; Query time: 29 msec
;; SERVER: 83.169.20.193#53(83.169.20.193)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr  5 13:54:50 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 77

$ dig @83.169.20.193 ns3.soonce.com

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4-P3 <<>> @83.169.20.193 ns3.soonce.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 7770
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns3.soonce.com.            IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
soonce.com.     86400   IN  SOA ns3.soonce.com. info.soonce.com. 2012022101 86400 7200 3600000 86400

;; Query time: 33 msec
;; SERVER: 83.169.20.193#53(83.169.20.193)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr  5 13:54:54 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 73
```

NS4 responds correctly:

```
$ dig @83.169.46.225 ns3.soonce.com

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4-P3 <<>> @83.169.46.225 ns3.soonce.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45021
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns3.soonce.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ns3.soonce.com.     14400   IN  A   83.169.46.225

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ns3.soonce.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns3.soonce.com.
ns3.soonce.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns4.soonce.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns4.soonce.com.     14400   IN  A   83.169.20.193

;; Query time: 31 msec
;; SERVER: 83.169.46.225#53(83.169.46.225)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr  5 13:57:30 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 96

$ dig @83.169.46.225 ns4.soonce.com

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4-P3 <<>> @83.169.46.225 ns4.soonce.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39553
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns4.soonce.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ns4.soonce.com.     14400   IN  A   83.169.20.193

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ns4.soonce.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns4.soonce.com.
ns4.soonce.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns3.soonce.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns3.soonce.com.     14400   IN  A   83.169.46.225

;; Query time: 31 msec
;; SERVER: 83.169.46.225#53(83.169.46.225)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr  5 13:57:33 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 96
```

NS4 is also not returning glue records.  There should be an `ADDITIONAL SECTION` with the A records for the two name servers after the `ANSWER SECTION`:

```
$ dig @83.169.20.193 soonce.com NS

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4-P3 <<>> @83.169.20.193 soonce.com NS
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44464
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;soonce.com.            IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
soonce.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns4.soonce.com.
soonce.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns3.soonce.com.

;; Query time: 81 msec
;; SERVER: 83.169.20.193#53(83.169.20.193)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr  5 14:00:01 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 64
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. This is a bit above my knowledge. What would be the smartest way to solve this? I have a bunch of domains running on these servers. Everything actually seem to be running fine, and I don't find any errors in cPanel, but I would like for it all to be correct. Do you have any resources online where I could find basic instructions towards solving this on my own?

Comment: IntoDNS is usually quite good.  I'm guessing that the only reason they didn't have a massive red flag on the "Nameservers A records" check was that they seem to always hit NS4 when doing that check.  I'm also guessing that Pingdom always hit NS3.  To fix it, make sure that `ns3.soonce.com` and `ns4.soonce.com` both have A records in NS3.  I have no idea about how to do this in cPanel.

Comment: OK. I have added ns4.soonce.com. 14400 IN A 83.169.20.193 to DNS Zone ns3.soonce.com and syncronized this to ns4 as well. (I have also added ns3 on the ns4 DNS Zone). I don't see any difference on Pingdom or IntoDNS. Maybe it takes a while?

Comment: Whoops, I just realised I got your name servers around the wrong way in the first part of my answer.  (probably due to NS4's IP address ending in "193").  NS3 is working fine.  NS4 is the one with both of the problems.

Comment: Alright, I've "Added A entrys for the name servers" on NS4 from cPanel/WHM. "Pingdom: Test finished successfully, no errors or warnings." .. A BIG Thank You to you!

Comment: I just tested with `dig`.  The two errors I saw are both gone now.