# Domain names have gone down - site still up

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ubuntu-12.04, reverse-dns, dns-hosting

I host a couple of websites on the same Ubuntu server, and as of today both domain names have gone down. PuTTY and FTP still both work so it is obviously a problem with the domain name.

I haven't made any changes with my registrar (namecheap), or my DNS host (clouDNS) which has both domains pointed to my IP address under the 'A' record.

The only other solution I can see must be some setting on my server, which is strange as I haven't changed anything there. I seem to recall editing a config file in order to set up the domains, but I cannot remember what it was at all!

Comment: What do you mean "gone down"? What symptoms have you seen, and what/how have you diagnosed this problem?

Comment: When I type the URL into my address bar I get 'Server Not Found'.

Comment: Why does "PuTTY and FTP still work" lead you to jump to the conclusion that your problem is with your "domain name" (whatever that means)? Also, voting to close this. There's nowhere near enough info here for someone to even venture a guess.

Comment: Because I can access my site via it's IP address (which is what PuTTY and FTP are configured with) but the domain names (I'm not sure how you don't understand this term) do not work.

Comment: When I run a DNS check I get "Failed to find name servers" and "No name servers found at child". I don't understand what this means since I haven't made any changes.

Comment: do we just downvote questions we're unable to answer then?

Comment: Questions get down voted when they aren't well formed and when they lack the detail needed to provide thoughtful, incisive answers.

Comment: No, we downvote questions that don't contain sufficient information for us to be able to diagnose them. As it stands you are basically asking us to guess why your DNS isn't working - my guess is cosmic rays as there was a bump in the Aurora Watch UK magnetometer readings this morning.

Comment: Failing to understand an error message is not a good reason to ignore it.  If you can provide the domain name in question we can do diagnostics on it but without that we're just guessing.  Googling the second error message finds [this answer I wrote a while ago](http://serverfault.com/a/377016/26130).

Comment: `Because I can access my site via it's IP address (which is what PuTTY and FTP are configured with)` you didn't tell us that. We aren't mind readers. PuTTY (SSH) and FTP are entirely different protocols than HTTP. Just saying that they work so your DNS is broken is not a sound judgement to make. Now, it's entirely possible that DNS is the cause given this new info, but leaving it out of your original question is why I downvoted it.

Comment: Also `a problem with the domain` doesn't mean anything. "A problem with my DNS servers" does mean something. You shouldn't get so feisty when *you* are the one that asked a question lacking in detail and clear terminology. Again, we aren't mind readers. Ambiguity in your part doesn't mean that everyone else is out to get you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably follow [ClouDNS's Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/ClouDNS).

ClouDNS are [currently posting about being under a DDoS attack](https://twitter.com/ClouDNS/status/340765447295229952).  I suspect this is the cause of your DNS issues.